# Conflict between team members

Tags: software-industry, management, conflict, conflict-resolution

I'm sure that most of you have experienced this type of situation. I'm wondering how did you come to a resolution.

**Scenario:**

I'm a software developer working in an agile team with 3 other developers. I have had a tension with two of my team members. And them also had a tension in some shape or form with themselves. The manager knows about this situation since all of us have talked to her more or less about what we've been experiencing.

To address this issue, she brought in a fifth developer so that he could be a tie breaker when there's a situation where exactly two people say one thing and the other two say something different. Unfortunately, this 5th person has some personality issues (based on the saying of all the developers on the team) which has caused everyone on the team to oppose his ideas and suggestions.
Given this situation, not only has the team condition gotten better, it is rapidly deteriorating.

**UPDATE 1:**

This 5th person has engaged himself in a lot of other company-related activities, such as travelling for recruiting events, and software POC in another team, that he barely has time to meet with his own team and do whatever the other developers do.

**UPDATE 2:**

All of the software developers on the team have joined the company around the same time. And we're all experienced. He is good at preaching and that's how he's gotten attention from the management.

**Question:**

How could I (or we) make the overall situation better?

**Excuse my broadness** *I’m so confused I don’t even know what is the right question to ask in this type of circumstances.*

Comment: Are you saying that when there's a technical disagreement (e.g. about which of several possible approaches to take), people are taking sides based on who presented each idea, rather than based on the merits of the ideas?

Comment: Like Carson said, we need a little more clarification as to what the arguments are usually about. Is it ideas, progress, development problems, project future or is it more generic things such as time at the office, a member's contributions, seniority issues, cooperation in general, etc. Please edit to specify a little more. Thanks

Comment: Your numbers don't add up. If you are working in a team where you have disagreement with 2 team members, and there are 3 other team members, then the team has 6 members. Adding one more developer (the "tie-breaker") makes it 7, not 5.

Comment: @Carson63000 you're exactly right. And this mainly stems from the fact he's presented many non-feasible technical ideas in the past.

Comment: "team better, team deteriorating,  4 other developers, the two employees and a 3rd person, brought in a fifth developer"   This story does not add up

Comment: @Frisbee sorry for the confusion. I updated the scenario. Please let me know if it still makes no sense.

Comment: Not it did not.  You are still on a team with 4 other developer but then brought in a fifth.  team better and deteriorating.  As developer you should be able to present numbers logic better then this.  If that how you write documentation?

Comment: @MohammadNajar Making multiple edits which do not add any more clarity will not help you get any answer to your question. Could you please nail down what your question is? We cannot help you figure out *your* question. "How can I improve the situation?" is not really a question we can answer with information like "tension between team members, fifth developer added as tie-breaker, personality issues, company related activities, team condition has gotten better but it is deteriorating".

Comment: To solve a conflict one needs to understand what the conflict is about. You are not providing any information about that, so this question can not be answered. Note that finding the reason for conflict is often more difficult than it seems, because when you ask people directly they will often lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This team has multiple longstanding and ongoing personality and professionalism problems. There are a couple of remedies.

Sack or discipline the manager and get someone in who knows how to manage a team and resolve conflicts and discipline the team.

Find which clique is doing the best job, and remove the other 2 to another position or the sidewalk. Or start training some replacements and get rid of the lot.

Break up the cliques by getting rid of just one (I'd probably do this, I'd find the least valuable or most troublesome and get rid of them) rather than adding one to make five, I'd get rid of one and add one to keep it at four.

Change the morale of this team in some fashion, really this is up to the manager since the team members seem incapable of doing so. But realistically this is just a fairly minor attitude adjustment that most teams handle themselves.